# Apply() function to a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame object which has 24 columns and each one has a different length. I would like to multiply every column by a vector of 24 values. I am thinking about using the apply function since I do not have any matrix. my guess is like:

```
trans_temp:
                    Ta.f Ta.f Ta.f Ta.f
1995-10-13 04:00:00 13.6 13.6 13.6 13.6
1995-10-13 05:00:00 13.6 13.6 13.6 13.6
1995-10-13 06:00:00 13.6 13.6 13.6 13.6
1995-10-13 07:00:00 13.5 13.5 13.5 13.5
1995-10-13 08:00:00 13.5 13.5 13.5 13.5
```

and my vector is

```
    x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24)
```

So I want the first column multiplied by 1, the second by 2, the third by 3 and so on. I can not multiply directlly because it is a data.frame object.

apply(trans_temp,x,MARGIN=2,fun)

Any help?

Comment: The columns of data frames cannot (by definition) have different lengths.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean here by "everyone has a different length"? How are they in a `data.frame` then?

Comment: please use `dput(head(df, 10))` to paste the output. It's tedious to remove the `spaces` in your row.names every time when trying to load your data.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a matrix directly and just multiply the data with it:

```
as.matrix(trans_temp) * col(trans_temp)
```

---

#### Benchmarking with eddi's

```
m <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(1e7), ncol=1000))
x <- seq_len(1000)
system.time(tt1 <- as.matrix(m) * col(m)) # 0.335 seconds
system.time(tt2 <- t(x*t(m))) # 0.505 seconds
identical(tt1, tt2) # TRUE
```

Comment: there's an easier way to create this matrix... (I remember DWin posting something much nicer).. can't get hold of it atm.

Comment: I do love the syntax of `apply` though, especially the quoting the operator, it just *looks* nicer. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track, but I don't understand how your columns have different lengths, unless you mean some contain, e.g. NA in them. Use `MARGIN = 1` to apply across rows.

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24)
t( apply(trans_temp , MARGIN = 1 , function(y) x * y ) )
```

You could even shorten the call like so:

```
 t( apply(trans_temp , 1 , `*` , x ) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach without using `apply`, that relies on R recycling behavior:

```
t(x*t(trans_temp))
```

This will probably be much faster than the other two approaches.

^^^ Not anymore after Arun's edits :) What this has going for it now is that you can have an arbitrary `x` (and if you want an arbitrary *operation* in addition to arbitrary `x`, then you'd go with Simon's answer).

Comment: @Arun haha, ok, but you can only multiply by that specific `x`, which I'm guessing was meant as an example only - maybe another edit can fix that? :)

Comment: @Arun, your solution only multiplies for `x=1:N`, but not any other `x`. Smth else to consider (this is probably minor) - if original data is in `data.frame` form, your solution slows down a **lot**.

Comment: @Arun - good call converting it to `matrix` first - you should probably edit the answer in addition to the benchmark